# How can I install the Buzz bundle on Symfony 2.2.0?

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php

I want to install the [Buzz bundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioBuzzBundle). On GitHub, the installation instructions suggest the `.bin/vendors install` method. However, that's not supported in Symfony 2.2.0.

Is there another way I could install the bundle? I've been trying to install it using [Composer](http://knplabs.com/blog/symfony2-with-composer/), but without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding in composer.json under `require` key:

```
"sensio/buzz-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Then follow the instructions [from step3](https://github.com/sensio/SensioBuzzBundle#step3-enable-the-bundle) onward

You'll also need to run `composer.phar update` after that.

And for future reference, lookup the package you need on [packagist.org](http://packagist.org). You'll find there what you need to put in composer.json

Comment: Thank you it worked. The composer downloaded and installed the bundle but an error was thrown while renaming the cache ` Warning: rename(/.../project_name/app/cache/dev,/.../app/cache/dev
  _old): Access is denied.` I have tried the `sleep(1)` solution but it didn'd work.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe just manually delete whatever is under app/cache and try again. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if my answer was useful to you ;)